# В чём разница между jdk, jre и jvm?

Tags: java, терминология, jvm

Есть три понятия - `jdk`, `jre` и `jvm`. Все эти понятия относятся к `java`, но в чём их разница?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Платформа java - что это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773045/)

Comment: Минусы ставят за "Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы (для отмены нажмите повторно)". Очевидно, что этот вопрос никакого стремления разобраться не отражает. Что такое jdk, jre и jvm написано примерно в 100500 местах.

Comment: @Эникейщик это мой вопрос + мой ответ

Comment: Открыв вопрос, посетитель не видит, что ответ тоже ваш. Да и из самого вопроса это тоже не ясно. Поэтому возникает впечатление, что вопрос задан человеком, который не хочет сам ничего искать, а хочет, чтобы ему все на блюдечке принесли.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### JVM

Расшифровывается как *Java Virtual Machine* (*виртуальная машина java*). Она нужна для запуска **уже скомпилированного** кода (*байт-кода*), который хранится в файлах `.class`. `jvm` входит в состав `jre` (о `jre` пойдёт речь дальше) и является как иногда говорят "сердцем jre" или если говорить более серьёзно, ключевым компонентом `jre`.

#### JRE

Расшифровывается как *Java Runtime Environment* (*среда выполнения java*).
`jre` нужна **для запуска уже готовых программ**. `jre` включает в себя `jvm` и всё, что нужно для запуска `java`-программ. `jre` содержит в себе стандартные `java`-библиотеки (например, `java.util`, `java.awt`, `java.io`, все их не перечислить, их **много**).

Если кратко, то:

```
jre = jvm + библиотеки
```

#### JDK

Расшифровывается как *Java Development Kit* (*комплект для разработки на java*). `jdk` включает в себя `jre` и инструменты для разработки. Что за инструменты? Все их я перечислять не буду, но вот некоторые из них:

- `javac` (компилятор)
- `jdb` (отладчик)
- `javadoc` (утилита для генерации документации по коду)
- `serialver` (утилита для генерации поля `serialdVersionUID`)
- многие другие...

Все эти инструменты **не нужны пользователю `java`-приложений, но нужны разработчику**.

Если кратко, то:

```
jdk = jvm + библиотеки + инструменты для разработки
```

Но тоже самое можно записать даже короче:

```
jdk = jre + инструменты разработки
```

#### P.S

Моей целью было рассказать, в чём разница между `jdk`, `jre`,`jvm` и вообще объяснить, что это такое и зачем оно надо, ведь лично я иногда вижу среди новичков путаницу в этих понятиях. Прошу не докапываться до деталей, которые связаны с тем, что в java 11+ вроде как выпускается только `jdk` (я в этом не уверен, поэтому про это не писал, но если это так, прошу не писать, что "ответ устарел").